# How can I get IdBabysitter in my join table with SQL transaction with node?

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, express, transactions

I am trying to get `IdBabysitter` in my join table with a SQL transaction with node but the result in my console in null for this one

My join table :

```
CREATE TABLE myProject.babysitter_compensation 
(
    IdBabysitter INT UNSIGNED,
    IdCompensation INT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (IdBabysitter) 
        REFERENCES myProject.babysitter (IdBabysitter),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdCompensation) 
        REFERENCES myProject.compensation (IdCompensation)      
);
```

My transaction :

```
const sql = [
    {
        sql:'INSERT INTO myProject.babysitter VALUE( NULL, :picture, :introduction,:nomad,:doctor, NOW(),LAST_INSERT_ID(),null);',
        sqlData: data ,
    },
    {
        sql: 'SET @IdBabysitter = LAST_INSERT_ID()',
    },
];

data.compensation.forEach(element => {
    sql.push(
        {
        sql:'INSERT INTO myProject.babysitter_compensation VALUE (@IdBabysitter, :compensation); ',
        sqlData: {compensation: element},
     },
   )    
});
```

I want to get `IdBabysitter` in `babysitter_compensation` table

Comment: If you add a tag for your specific DBMS, such as [sql-server], [oracle], [mysql], etc., you will reach a larger audience including those who specialize in the specific DBMS you are working on.

Comment: Try, instead of relying on session variables, you should fetch the last inserted ID (IdBabysitter) in your Node.js code and then use it in subsequent queries.